# sql concat columns from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I'm looking to create a view that concatenates two columns from two tables together. the scenario is as follows:

Table1 - Parent

```
Id
fname
lname
age
```

Table2 – child

```
Id
parent_id
fname
age
```

view – child

```
Id
firstlast
age
```

Given that the child table has a fk reference to parent’s ID, and parent has a lname column that I’m interested in, how would one create a view that contains

child(id),

`child(fname)` .  . `parent(lname)` as fullname

child(age)

the fullname would appear 'Jimmy Smith'

Comment: `SELECT CONCAT(table1.column, ', ', table2.column) FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON [condition goes here]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following :-

```
select c.id, concat(c.fname, p.lname) as full_name from
parent p
inner join
child c
on p.id = c.parent_id
```

Comment: Thanks, fast reply, worked great. just gotta add the space in there :)